# Escaped symbol on get parameter

Tags: php, get, escaping

I have a string has encrypted but with some symbol `qwfKOEK==dwk&f`

What if I need pass this string to a parameter:

```
www.example.php?string=qwfKOEK==dwk&f

$_GET["string"]
```

But I can’t get the string cause the symbol interrupt it.

Anyway to escape the symbol?

I had try [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) but seems not working, any possible way to escape the symbol and `$_GET` the original string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *URL value* needs to be *URL encoded* using `urlencode` or [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode).
The difference between the two is two slightly different standards for encoding, whereby the `rawurlencode` variant is generally preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to put this sting in a GET parameter, definitely it'll not be accepted as it explodes at "=" sign. You can try passing the same though a POST parameter or try changing the encryption technique. I hope this may solve the problem. plus, html_entity_decode() doesnt apply to "=" sign.